# How to inherit the class of function?

Tags: python-3.7

How to inherit the class of function**

This is code:

```py
def A():
    x = int(input('entrée x:'))
    y = int(input('entrée x:'))
    return x,y

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.add()
        self.sup()
    def add(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)
    def sup(self):
        print(self.x - self.y)

A()
obj = B()
```

This is [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHHsP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to use the tuple of values returned by your ***function*** `A()` to initialize attributes of your ***class*** `B`. First of all, I would modify `B` so that needed values can be passed at instantiation time:

```py
 class B:
     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.add()
         self.sup()

     def add(self):
         print(self.x + self.y)

     def sup(self):
         print(self.x - self.y)
```

You can now use your `B` class with whatever values you like:

```py
B(1, 2)
B(45, 70)
```

And as a particular case, you can use your `A` function to ask for values interactively. You just have to use the `*` operator to expand the returned tuple to the expected argument list (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists))

```py
B(*A())
```

Comment: If there is a large set of values ​​in the function you want to inherit the class. Is the same method as between the class and the class?

Comment: I am sorry but neither your initial question or comment are really clear. I tried to answer from what I understood of your code example. I you really want inheritance, this should take place between 2 classes, not between a function and a class. Have a look at the documentation here: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Comment: Thanks. I understand